# Categories in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, categories

I want to know what is the best way to build my database to deal with this problem :

I need to manage products. Each product has his own variables. For exemple, a table and a chair won't have the same parameters.

I have a lot of categories :

- Motorcycles : Price   year    Km  Brand   Models  CYLENDER
- House       : Price   Date    Rooms   m2 etc
- ...

Does someone have an idea to manage all those variables ?

Thanks :)

Comment: To get a good answer to this question, you will probably need to be more specific about some things.  EG, distinguish properties that ALL products have from properties that only SOME products have.  Perhaps you have categories of products that all have the same kinds of properties.  If you can classify and categorize your data clearly, the database design will follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can store categories in table like usual and then create another table called category_properties which contains categoryId as foreign key and propertyId which you will create another lookup table named propertyEnum contains any property you need using this technique will create dynamic properties as you much as you need